# map reduce function to count the documents- mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a Collection with the following fields:

```
TestTable
{
        "ID"
        "Name"
        "Ver" 
        "Serial"
        "DateTime"
        "FeatureID"
        "FeatureName"
}
```

I want to have a map reduce function to get the count of the records in a particular Year.
The map reduce function i wrote is:

```
map= function(){
    year= Date.UTC(this.DateTime.getFullYear());
    emit({year: year}, {count: 1});
}

reduce= function(key, values){
    var count=0;
    for(v in values){
        count+= v['count'];
    });
    return {count: count};
}
```

Now the output should give the count of douments in each year. Is the map reduce function correct?

The result i got is:

```
> db.Years.find()
{ "_id" : { "year" : NaN }, "value" : { "count" : NaN } }
> db.Years.find().count()
1
```

Which is not what i expected.

**edited**

one of the TestTable document:

```
> db.TestTable.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("527c48e99000cf10bc2a1d82"),
        "ID" : "LogID16587",
        "Name" : "LogName15247",
        "Ver" : "VersionID11",
        "Serial" : "ProductID727",
        "DateTime" : ISODate("1998-12-15T18:30:00Z"),
        "FeatureID" : "FeatureID465",
        "FeatureName" : "FeatureName 1460"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) requires both year and month parameters.  So your `map` function should look like this instead:

```js
map= function(){
    year= Date.UTC(this.DateTime.getFullYear(), 0);
    emit({year: year}, {count: 1});
}
```

Also, don't use `in` to iterate over the elements of an array in your `reduce` method as it doesn't work in the way you're using it.  Use a traditional `for` loop instead:

```js
reduce= function(key, values){
    var count=0;
    for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        count += values[i]['count'];
    };
    return {count: count};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How should i change the function, if i want to get the count of documents in each Year, month, and Day?

Comment: @user2439903 You should post that as a separate question.